# Java Spring custom Enum to String conversion in JSON Serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, enums

I'm trying to convert an enum value into a custom string as part of a JSON response in a Java Spring application. I've attempted to override the enum's toString method and create a Spring converter but both attempts don't seem to work.

#### Sample Controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/endpoint", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RestController
public class RecommenderController {
    ...
    @GetMapping("test")
    public List<MyEnum> test() {
        return new ArrayList<>() {{
            this.add(MyEnum.SAMPLE);
        }};
    }
}
```

#### Enum

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    SAMPLE("sample"), OTHER_SAMPLE("other sample");
    private final String name;
    public MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This code returns the response `["SAMPLE"]` although I want it to return `["sample"]`. Is there a way to implement this in Spring?

Comment: You can simply return llist of string, instead List of enum

Comment: This is a minimal use case - the enum is nested inside of other datatypes, and I am trying to keep it as an enum to remove primitive obsession

Comment: Because you return a List of ENUM type, not their value. If you want use their value you must return a List of String in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, then behind the scenes you are using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to perform all the JSON serialization and deserialization.  So it's a matter of configuring Jackson for your protocol objects.

In this case, it's probably most straightforward tell Jackson that it can make a single JSON value for your instance of `MyEnum` with the [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    SAMPLE("sample"), OTHER_SAMPLE("other sample");
    private final String name;

    public MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

`@JsonValue` has a bonus, as described in its Javadoc:

> NOTE: when use for Java enums, one additional feature is that value returned by annotated method is also considered to be the value to deserialize from, not just JSON String to serialize as. This is possible since set of Enum values is constant and it is possible to define mapping, but can not be done in general for POJO types; as such, this is not used for POJO deserialization.

So if you have the same Enum definition in your application that receives the list, it will deserialize the human readable value back into your Enum.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the `@JsonValue` annotation in the enum definition:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    ...
    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```